# How do I iterate through only the top level keys of a nested object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

For example, if I were to iterate through the following object:

```
{
  "Crows": {
    "players": {
      "Ben": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Ty": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Pigeons": {
    "players": {
      "Bill": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tim": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Seagulls": {
    "players": {
      "Bob": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tom": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to only iterate and manipulate the top level keys, which in this case are "Crows", "Pigeons", and "Seagulls".

When I try to iterate with a traditional `for (var key in data)` loop, a console.log of the keys gives me every key in the object, including the nested ones like "players". How would I only loop through parent keys?

Comment: what do you mean with *parent keys*?

Comment: There's no such thing as a _JSON Object_. JSON is always a String.

Comment: I can't repeat the behavior you  mention. `for (k in data){ console.log(k) }` just gives me the expected top-level keys. Maybe you can make a snippet that shows this behavior.

Comment: What is your expected output? if all you want is the keys then look into `Object.keys()`.

Comment: I've edited out all mentions of "JSON" for now because there's nothing related to JSON in the question. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, JSON is a string format for transporting data over HTTP/HTTPS. You don't iterate JSON, you parse it back into a regular JavaScript object and then you do whatever you like with that object. What you've posted is just a plain JavaScript object, so it looks like you've already done that parsing.

So, in your case:

```js
let result = {
  "Crows": {
    "players": {
      "Ben": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Ty": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Pigeons": {
    "players": {
      "Bill": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tim": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Seagulls": {
    "players": {
      "Bob": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tom": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  }
};

for(var prop in result){
  console.log(prop);                      // Just get the property name only  
  console.log(result[prop]);              // Or, get the data held in that property
  
  // Or, dig deeper still. Either of the following syntaxes will work:
  console.log(result[prop]["players"]);   
  console.log(result[prop].players);     
}
```

Comment: @RandyCasburn No, I'd rather not. I use the code that the OP posts. The OP has not posted JSON, he's posted a plain JavaScript object and so that's what I'll show how to use. In my experience, novices call the *object* they extracted from the JSON, a "JSON object", when in fact, they just have an object.

Comment: Now that the OP has edited the question to remove the term JSON, my comment is no longer relevant. But now no longer is the JSON comment in your answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The OP didn't make that edit, and so referencing it in my answer is still relevant. With all respect, I've been at this for a while and understand how to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `for...in` loop:

```js
const data = {
  "Crows": {
    "players": {
      "Ben": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Ty": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Pigeons": {
    "players": {
      "Bill": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tim": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Seagulls": {
    "players": {
      "Bob": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tom": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  }
}

for (let key in data) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Or collect them into one array:

```js
const data = {
  "Crows": {
    "players": {
      "Ben": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Ty": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Pigeons": {
    "players": {
      "Bill": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tim": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  },
  "Seagulls": {
    "players": {
      "Bob": {
        "jersey #": "1B"
      },
      "Tom": {
        "jersey #": "2B"
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

Comment: OK @RandyCasburn, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Why would the service have to be RESTful? And how is the origin of the object relevant to the question?

Comment: Edited @RandyCasburn.

Comment: Now that the OP has changed the question to remove JSON, it isn't relevant any longer.

Comment: Starting with a string, doesn't explain the behavior that iterating through the keys results in `including the nested ones like "players".`

Comment: What do you mean @MarkMeyer?

Comment: @JackBashford the OP says `When I try to iterate with a traditional for (var key in data) loop, a console.log of the keys gives me every key in the object, including the nested ones like "players".` If the data was a string, this wouldn't happen. You would get the numeric indexes of the string with `for…in`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have edited my post, sorry for the confusion.